# Apache Tuning on Server with Nothing Else

Tags: apache, cakephp, amazon-web-services

We have a site that may get some significant traffic due to some significant exposure (TV) and we want to do our best to be ready. I'm on AWS, and have moved our MySQL database to its own RDS instance.

Apache is now essentially the only thing sitting on the Web server. I've allocated a "large" instance,  with 7.5GB of RAM and 2 CPUs.

I'm concerned that my ignorance of Apache config is keeping me from getting the most from the box and I'm especially concerned about the MinSpareServers, MaxSpareServers, and StartServers settings.

We're serving a cakePHP app.

Each instance seems to take 22MB of memory after spawning

Thanks for any insight you can supply

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check that your ELB configuration can handle the traffic spikes (if you're using ELB). The point here is that ELB can only scale 50% every five minutes (roughly), so it's not going to handle traffic spikes well. Additional information [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479)

If you're not using ELB, I would recommend adding a load balancer in front of your server for additional piece of mind (I'm using HAProxy specifically because our traffic tends to be spikey). This way, you can rapidly add new servers in case of problems.

Back to your question of Apache tuning, you should make sure that you're using all the available RAM on your machine. This means setting up a simple load test (using siege or apache ab) and raising the MaxSpareServers and MaxClients setting until saturating your EC2 instance. Also, make sure you're running MPM Worker instead of Prefork, I've seen substantially better results. Given that the machine has only two CPU's, having a very large number of concurrent apache processes might not help much, as the CPU might get saturated.

Performance will vary greatly based on the application you're actually running and you might encounter other bottlenecks such as the RDS instance, but a properly cached solution should yield 10-40k RPM's on the server you mentioned.

Scaling is usually something that needs testing and optimising, but I hope this helps a little.